# Indexing through list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, indexing

Considering a list of matrices of the following structure

```
m1 <- matrix(floor(runif(156,min=0, max=10)), ncol=12)
m2 <- matrix(floor(runif(120,min=0, max=10)), ncol=12)
m3 <- matrix(floor(runif(120,min=0, max=10)), ncol=12)
m4 <- matrix(floor(runif(204,min=0, max=10)), ncol=12)
l1<-list(m1,m2,m3,m4)
```

How can I recover a list for a range within all listed matrices? I know a solution which works , given in the example below:

```
lapply(l1, function(x)x[,seq(1,12,2)])
```

But I am new to R and find indexing lists rather hard to understand. Can anyone please explain in newbie-terms and/or provide alternative solutions? I often get stuck in similar situations when analysing my data and waste long time refreshing on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking for the number of columns, it is `ncol` i.e. `lapply(l1, function(x) x[, seq(1, ncol(x), 2)])`

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make your code a little clearer by writing:

```
lapply(l1, function(x) {
    x[,c(TRUE, FALSE)]
}
```

So what is happening? You take your list: `l1` and passit to `lapply`. `lapply` breaks up your list into list items and passes each one iteratively to a function that you define in the second argument of `lapply`. This function has a single argument `x` which becomes your single item in the list  `l1`. These pieces: `x` can now be processed by your code in the function. You would like to extract every second column from these matrices, so you index the 1st, 3rd, 5th and so on in that matrix x.

The indexing itself of x is `[row, column]` so you are asking for all the rows by specifying nothing before the comma and some of the columns by specifying `c(TRUE, FALSE)` after the comma. The vector `c(TRUE, FALSE)` is repeated for as long as the number of columns in you matrix so you don't have to use: `seq(1, 12, 2)` to get the indexes you want.

In my opinion there is not other obvious solution to this problem you have  already specified the best solution yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation! I must study this rationale for some time now.